# How can I read endlessly from a Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm switching my old datalayer (using Queues) to the "new" and recommended Dataset API. I'm using it for the first time, so I'm providing code examples in case I got something fundamentally wrong.

I create my Dataset from a generator (that will read a file, and provide n samples). It's a small dataset and n_iterations >> n_samples, so I simply want to read this dataset over and over again, ideally shuffled.

```
sample_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( data_generator(filename),  
    (tf.uint8, tf.uint8), (tf.TensorShape([256,256,4]), tf.TensorShape([256,256,1]))
)
```

with datagenerator:

```
class data_generator:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename= filename

    def __call__(self):
        with filename.open() as f:
           for idx in f: yield img[idx], label[idx]
```

To actually use the data, I got that I need to define an `Iterator`

```
sample = sample_set.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

and then we are set to read data

```
while True:
    try: my_sample = sess.run(sample)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: break   # this happens after dset is read once
```

But all available Iterators seem to be "finite", in the way that they read a dataset only once.

Is there a simple way to make reading from the Dataset endless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datasets have [`repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) and [`shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) methods.

```py
BUF_SIZE = 100 # choose it depending on your data
sample_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( data_generator(filename),  
    (tf.uint8, tf.uint8), (tf.TensorShape([256,256,4]), 
    tf.TensorShape([256,256,1]))
).repeat().shuffle(BUF_SIZE)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I had in mind! I'll pick this one since the shuffle is really useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Dataset.repeat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) transformation will repeat a dataset endlessly if you don't pass an explicit `count` to it:

```
sample_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    data_generator(filename), (tf.uint8, tf.uint8),
    (tf.TensorShape([256,256,4]), tf.TensorShape([256,256,1])))

# Repeats `sample_set` endlessly.
sample_set = sample_set.repeat()

sample = sample_set.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Comment: is the `dataset.repeat()` functionality implemented in the way [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366766/6409572) is (i.e. kind of like this: `try: my_sample = sess.run(sample) except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: sess.run(sample_set_init_op)  # re-initialize on same dataset`)? Because my log still shows "`Out of range: ...`-Errors, but it continues to run.

Comment: It might be printing this each time the original `data_generator()` reaches the end of one repetition. (I believe this extra logging was removed in a more recent version of TensorFlow.)

Answer (score 0):

The **reinitializable Iterator** will work with reinitializing on the same dataset, so this code will read the same dataset over and over again:

```
sample = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(sample_set.output_types,
                                         sample_set.output_shapes).get_next()

sample_it.make_initializer(sample_set)     # create initialize op

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(sample_set_init_op)           # initialize in the beginning

    while True:
        try: 
             my_sample = sess.run(sample)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
             sess.run(sample_set_init_op)  # re-initialize on same dataset
```

Comment: This might work for others, **BUT** apart from feeling dirty to produce and catch errors like this, this requires "restarting" the graph. In this toy example the graph is trivial, but usually the datainput is part of a large training graph. For my main-loop with checkpoint management and lots of other stuff, including the `output = sess.run()`, I use a wrapper provided by someone else, so basically I have no access to the `sess.run()` and would love the model to handle the "infinite data read" itself (not requiring me to rerun the erroring model).